# A first-countable, compact space which is non-separable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space which is first countable and compact. Is $X$ necessarily separable?  Is $X$ necessarily second countable?

Comment: $[0,1]^\kappa$ is a counterexample if $\kappa>\aleph_0$.

Comment: tetori, this space is separable for $\kappa \leqslant 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Is $[0,1]^\kappa$ first countable for $\kappa>\aleph_0$?  It would seem that the collection of open sets $\{U_\gamma\mid \gamma\in \kappa\}$ where $U_\gamma$ is $[0,1/2)$ in the $\gamma$ coordinate and $[0,1]$ elsewhere would be an uncountable family of open sets that wouldn't be contained in any countable local basis at the point 0.

Comment: This is right. The character of each point in this cube is $\kappa$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/), an online database containing information from Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*, lists the following examples of [first countable, compact, non-separable spaces](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=First%20Countable%2BCompact%2B%7ESeparable).

Concentric circles

Either-or topology

Lexicographic order topology on the unit square

Uncountable excluded point topology

Comment: You can learn more about these spaces by viewing the [search result](http://topology.jdabbs.com/search?q=%7B%22and%22%3A%5B%7B%2228%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%2216%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%2226%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%7D). (Paul, thank you for promoting the site.)

Comment: @AustinMohr You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

No, they need not be separable (so not second-countable either). The [lexicographic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square) is a counter-example. Other examples include [Alexandrov's duplicates](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/alexandroff-double-circle/) of uncountable compact metric spaces.